# Find a partition of set $\mathbb{Z}$ in 4 parts | all parts are infinite in size

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find a partition of the set $\mathbb{Z}$ with four parts that are infinite in size.

A collection of sets $A$ can be considered a partition if:

1) $A =  A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n$

AND

2) $A_1, A_2, ... , A_n $ are mutually disjoint.

Could these four sets be considered a partition?

$A_1 = \{n \in \mathbb{Z} : n = 2p \text{ for } p \in \mathbb{Z} : P \geq 0\}$

$A_2 = \{n \in \mathbb{Z} : n = 2p -1 \text{ for } p \in \mathbb{Z} : P > 0\}$

$A_3 = \{n \in \mathbb{Z} : n = -2p  \text{ for } p \in \mathbb{Z} : P > 0\}$

$A_4 = \{n \in \mathbb{Z} : n = -2p +1 \text{ for } p \in \mathbb{Z} : P > 0\}$

If $A_1$ contains all positive even numbers including 0, $A_2$ contains all odd positive numbers, and $A_3$ and $A_4$ contain the negative equivalents, am I covering all bases here?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Yes, this is one of the infinitely many correct answers here.  There are of course much more exotic answers, e.g. into the fibonacci numbers, the lucas numbers which are not fibonacci, the catalan numbers which are neither fibonacci nor lucas, and everything else.  As for more mundane examples, you could partition it based on their first digit such as "numbers whose first digit is a 1" vs "whose first digit is a 2" vs "first digit is a 3" vs all else, or numbers who when divided by 4 give remainder 0, give remainder 1, give remainder 2, or give remainder 3.  Again, there are many correct ways.

Comment: Very interesting, I've never heard of the lucas or catalan numbers, I'll have to check them out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description looks good.

A similar even easier partition to describe is given by "modular classes" i.e. you look at the remainder that an integer leaves on division by $4$. Group those that give the same remainder.

That is , for $k=0,1,2,3$ , define:
$$
S_k= \{4n+k : n \in \mathbb Z\}
$$

then note that $S_k$ are disjoint (a number cannot leave two different remainders) and $S_k$ cover $\mathbb Z$ (every number leaves some remainder).

The advantage of this approach is that you could have used it to partition $\mathbb Z$ into any finite number of classes, all infinite.